# Overriding a Javascript function that is run when the DOM is ready

Tags: javascript, jstree

I want to override `$.vakata.css.add_css and $.vakata.css.add_sheet` functions in the jstree library 
 http://static.jstree.com/v.1.0pre/jquery.jstree.js

I have another js file which I want implement my own version of `add_css` and `add_sheet` function. I don't want to touch the third party jstree library.

The problem is that I cannot override these functions because the jstree executes these when the DOM is ready.

Is there a way I can stop jstree executing its `$.vakata.css.add_css` or `$.vakata.css.add_sheet` and use my functions instead which changing the jstree code.

Comment: Can't you just say `$.vakata.css.add_css = yourfunction`? (In a script block that runs after the include of jstree.js but before the DOM is ready?)

Comment: look up "monkey patching" and closures ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try executing before the dom is loaded

```
$.vakata.css.add_css = function() {
    // your code
    // ...or call your function
};
```

This will replace the vakata method but keep the execution after the dom is loaded

Comment: I tried that but I get "Unable to get value of the property 'css'". It would be good if I could bind to something in jstree that tells me that the jstree file has loaded. At the point I can override add_css. Also I am using requirejs

Comment: Well that means the exec was run before there was a vakata object, if you have a look at line 51 in the js-file you linked you will find what you are looking for. The object is closed from the outside world, if you want to modify it you will have to change the source.

Comment: Ah ok. Thanks Eric. I thought I'd had to edit the source. I wanted to avoid that in case of upgrade issues. I will look at an alternative